# Save R script in current working directory

Tags: r

Is there a command to save the currently open R script as a .R file in the current working directory?

Comment: This seems a chicken-and-egg situation. How will R know what file is "currently open"?

Comment: could you give some context ?

Comment: Say if I wanted to save what's in the current script with the date and time attached to the filename via sys.date() .

Comment: Why do you want this? Which editor/GUI/IDE are you using?

Comment: And you don't want to use `Ctrl+S`, but do this from R, which can't know which Script you have opened?

Comment: Is it not possible to put something in a script?

Comment: @user1987097 What is the reason you want to do this? And you want to save the actual script, or what has been put in output below your script, in the `Workspace image`?

Comment: R doesn't know your script. I don't know if RStudio provides an API that you can use. However, the whole request buffles me, because it seems useless.

Comment: @Roland to save the user typing out the date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a second script like this:

**Main.R**

```
# Name of the original file
FileO <- "FileO.R"

D <- Sys.Date()

todaysFile <- paste(D,FileO,sep = "-")

file.copy(from = FileO, to = todaysFile)
source(todaysFile)
```

This script takes the name of the original script, appends the date to its name, saves it with the new name and then executes it.

I hope this is what you are looking for.